# How to loop informatica sessions

Tags: loops, informatica-powercenter

I want to load one table for data for say 1 month starting from 1 April to 30 April in successive manner.
i.e after loading data for 1 April, date should automatically increment to 2, load the data and increment and so on, till its 30 April.
Also, data of 2 April depends on 1 April data. So i cannot give a date range to load randomly.

How can I do it?
It would be preferable to get the loads done in single session run, instead of running the session for several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the source data by date and use a Transaction Control transformation to enforce a commit every time the date changes.